# Elegant way to sort on multiple properties that might be undefined

Tags: javascript, sorting

I'm trying to sort an array with JavaScript. The objects should be sorted based on several properties (about 4 in my real scenario), which are all strings that may also be null or undefined. A null or undefined value should be treated similar, and should be "earlier" in the sorted array than items with values.

I used unit tests to spec the behavior, and the simplest code that would work (which is really, really verbose) is the following:

```js
function myComparer(a, b) {
  if (!!a.label && !!b.label) {
    var diff = a.label.localeCompare(b.label);
    if (diff !== 0) {
      return diff;
    }
  }
  
  if (!!b.label && !a.label) {
    return -1;
  }
  
  if (!!a.label && !b.label) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  if (!!a.code && !!b.code) {
    var diff = a.code.localeCompare(b.code);
    if (diff !== 0) {
      return diff;
    }
  }
  
  if (!!b.code && !a.code) {
    return -1;
  }
  
  if (!!a.code && !b.code) {
    return 1;
  }
  
  return 0;
}

test("Can compare given labels", function() {
  var result = [{label: 'Z'}, {label: 'A'}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].label, 'A');
  strictEqual(result[1].label, 'Z');
});

test("Can compare null label with given label", function() {
  var result = [{label: null}, {label: 'A'}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].label, null);
  strictEqual(result[1].label, 'A');
});

test("Can compare null label with given label - reverse", function() {
  var result = [{label: 'Z'}, {label: null}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].label, null);
  strictEqual(result[1].label, 'Z');
});

test("Can compare given codes", function() {
  var result = [{code: 'Z'}, {code: 'A'}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].code, 'A');
  strictEqual(result[1].code, 'Z');
});

test("Can compare null code with given code", function() {
  var result = [{code: null}, {code: 'A'}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].code, null);
  strictEqual(result[1].code, 'A');
});

test("Can compare null code with given code - reverse", function() {
  var result = [{code: 'Z'}, {code: null}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].code, null);
  strictEqual(result[1].code, 'Z');
});

test("Will sort on label before code", function() {
  var result = [
    {id: 1, label: 'Z', code: 'Z'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Z', code: 'A'},
    {id: 3, label: 'A', code: 'Z'},
    {id: 4, label: 'A', code: 'A'}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].id, 4);
  strictEqual(result[1].id, 3);
  strictEqual(result[2].id, 2);
  strictEqual(result[3].id, 1);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.12.0.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.12.0.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
```

This will not be pretty for 4 or more properties (I figured you can imagine this, I tried to keep my example a bit smaller).

I can think of several ways to improve this, but I struggle to balance:

- Performance
- Readability
- Verbosity

Which is why I figured I'd ask here: do you have any suggestions on how to refactor my version into something more elegant?

PS. I'm happy to use ECMAScript5 stuff, I can use polyfills if anything's missing in browsers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I saw this because you linked to it from a Knockout-related question on Stack Overflow. My first suggestion is to create a function that compares a single property, since the comparison of each property is the same. You can also use some other shortcuts.

```
function compareProperty(a, b) {
  return (a || b) ? (!a ? -1 : !b ? 1 : a.localeCompare(b)) : 0;
}

function myComparer(a, b) {
  return compareProperty(a.label, b.label) || compareProperty(a.code, b.code);
}
```

```js
function compareProperty(a, b) {
  return (a || b) ? (!a ? -1 : !b ? 1 : a.localeCompare(b)) : 0;
}

function myComparer(a, b) {
  return compareProperty(a.label, b.label) || compareProperty(a.code, b.code);
}




test("Can compare given labels", function() {
  var result = [{label: 'Z'}, {label: 'A'}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].label, 'A');
  strictEqual(result[1].label, 'Z');
});

test("Can compare null label with given label", function() {
  var result = [{label: null}, {label: 'A'}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].label, null);
  strictEqual(result[1].label, 'A');
});

test("Can compare null label with given label - reverse", function() {
  var result = [{label: 'Z'}, {label: null}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].label, null);
  strictEqual(result[1].label, 'Z');
});

test("Can compare given codes", function() {
  var result = [{code: 'Z'}, {code: 'A'}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].code, 'A');
  strictEqual(result[1].code, 'Z');
});

test("Can compare null code with given code", function() {
  var result = [{code: null}, {code: 'A'}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].code, null);
  strictEqual(result[1].code, 'A');
});

test("Can compare null code with given code - reverse", function() {
  var result = [{code: 'Z'}, {code: null}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].code, null);
  strictEqual(result[1].code, 'Z');
});

test("Will sort on label before code", function() {
  var result = [
    {id: 1, label: 'Z', code: 'Z'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Z', code: 'A'},
    {id: 3, label: 'A', code: 'Z'},
    {id: 4, label: 'A', code: 'A'}].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].id, 4);
  strictEqual(result[1].id, 3);
  strictEqual(result[2].id, 2);
  strictEqual(result[3].id, 1);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.12.0.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.12.0.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
```

Using the conditional-expression operator greatly shortens the code, but the biggest gain comes from using a function for common code. I also rearranged the conditional logic so that it doesn't have to make as many comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the Michael Best answer, nesting both functions can make the sorting clearer and less verbose:

```
function myComparer(a, b) {
  function compareProperty(property) {
    const ap = a[property]
    const bp = b[property]

    return !(ap || bp) ? 0 : (!ap ? -1 : !bp ? 1 : ap.localeCompare(bp))
  }

  return compareProperty("label") || compareProperty("code")
}
```

```js
function myComparer(a, b) {
  function compareProperty(property) {
    const ap = a[property]
    const bp = b[property]

    return !(ap || bp) ? 0 : (!ap ? -1 : !bp ? 1 : ap.localeCompare(bp))
  }

  return compareProperty("label") ||
    compareProperty("code")
}




test("Can compare given labels", function() {
  var result = [{
    label: 'Z'
  }, {
    label: 'A'
  }].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].label, 'A');
  strictEqual(result[1].label, 'Z');
});

test("Can compare null label with given label", function() {
  var result = [{
    label: null
  }, {
    label: 'A'
  }].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].label, null);
  strictEqual(result[1].label, 'A');
});

test("Can compare null label with given label - reverse", function() {
  var result = [{
    label: 'Z'
  }, {
    label: null
  }].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].label, null);
  strictEqual(result[1].label, 'Z');
});

test("Can compare given codes", function() {
  var result = [{
    code: 'Z'
  }, {
    code: 'A'
  }].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].code, 'A');
  strictEqual(result[1].code, 'Z');
});

test("Can compare null code with given code", function() {
  var result = [{
    code: null
  }, {
    code: 'A'
  }].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].code, null);
  strictEqual(result[1].code, 'A');
});

test("Can compare null code with given code - reverse", function() {
  var result = [{
    code: 'Z'
  }, {
    code: null
  }].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].code, null);
  strictEqual(result[1].code, 'Z');
});

test("Will sort on label before code", function() {
  var result = [{
      id: 1,
      label: 'Z',
      code: 'Z'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      label: 'Z',
      code: 'A'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      label: 'A',
      code: 'Z'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      label: 'A',
      code: 'A'
    }
  ].sort(myComparer);
  strictEqual(result[0].id, 4);
  strictEqual(result[1].id, 3);
  strictEqual(result[2].id, 2);
  strictEqual(result[3].id, 1);

});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.12.0.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-1.12.0.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="qunit"></div>
<div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
```